# Junior professorship (W1) in Germany without full German proficiency

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, language, germany

I am a Computer Science PhD student aiming for an Academic career. One of the options I am considering after I receive the degree is to apply for a W1 professor position in Germany (Junior professor).

My question is very specific to Germany. Is there a chance I can become a Junior professor without being fluent in German? Most of the job postings I come across are actually written in German. Some of them do not mention German knowledge as a requirement, but it could be that it goes without saying.

I know that many courses, particularly in master programs, are taught in English. So I am sure there is a capacity to teach in English. But I am wondering if there is a culture of preferring and only accepting German speakers. Because if that's the case, I should start putting back up options.

Obviously I could work on my German. But my question is assuming I did not reach the required level of German until the time I start applying for Junior professorship.

Comment: I've seen it happen that someone with only very basic command of German got a professorship in Germany, but I guess you have to be their first choice by far to get the position.

Comment: I think it is quite unlikely to get a Juniorprofessor position without any PostDoc - or similar - experience. Regarding the knowledge of German, typically most BSc programs in CS in Germany are taught in German, and as a Juniorprofessor, you will generally be expected to teach at that level as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can certainly apply. I don't think German language proficiency will have a major impact on your chances, as long as your research record/profile is good and you are able to at least understand some German in case a student asks in German. Computer science students usually need to be able understand at least some English...

I disagree with earlier posts that you would be "expected to give undergraduate-level lectures". On the contrary, they would usually prefer you to give smaller (=specialized) classes until you have some more experience... Sometimes, you can find this in the advertisement.

However, **German academia is very competitive**!

We do not have a lot of professor positions, and it appears quite common to take 6-12 months to fill a position (make that 12-24 months for full professor positions)... according to Times Higher Education, Germany has the **worst student-to-professors ratio** ([source](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/excellence-by-numbers)). You may say, the German system is very efficient. We have few professors, yet we have a very high output of very educated people!

As far as I can tell, you need to:

- be the best match for their plan
- have had some third-party funding
- have a strong track record (papers in top venues, awards, 100+ citations)
- have been at different universities
- have some teaching experience
- convince them in person

So don't be surprised if you don't hear anything back (not even an invitation to present) on your first applications. Maybe you will get a **negative reply after a year or two**, when the new professor has arrived at his position. Maybe not even that. So, **do not wait for an answer when you apply**. Continue sending applications and making backup plans.

There is a reason why Postdocs ("Mittelbau") complain a lot in Germany (according to a recent study, even 50% of Junior Professors consider quitting academia because of the lack of perspective - most junior professor positions are currently not tenure-track). They do a lot of the work (both in research and teaching) and usually have only up to three years of work contract.

Comment: "You may say, the German system is very efficient. We have few professors, yet we have a very high output of very educated people!" I may say this certainly made my day!

Comment: You may also say the German system is very inefficient: Both in adding new positions, as well as in filling the existing positions (it seems to always take at least one year to fill a professor position). But either way, academic output is good. KDD2014 had [acceptance rate by country](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/kdd2014-researchtrack-all-140827130335-phpapp01/95/data-science-view-of-the-kdd-2014-7-638.jpg?cb=1409145093) with Germany being a positive outlier (it's clipped, because it was the add-later surprise) - so we do have quality.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the position, but in general full German proficiency is not required for German professorships.